# Why a non existent vue component rendering?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Why is this Vue template rendering? h(App2), but App2 does not exists? What is wrong? Thanks a lot for your help.

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

**App0.vue**

```
    <template>
        <div>
            Hi there!
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            name: "App1"
        }
    </script>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App2 from './App0';


new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     render: h =>  h(App2)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `components` option:

```
new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     components: { App2 },
     render: h =>  h(App2)
});
```

Comment: I did not have to add it and it still renders.

Comment: Yes, `components: { App2 },` is need when you use `template` option. Because you are using `render` it uses special createElement function to render App2 into HTML